# Get properties value in each field in main window

Tags: c#, reflection, properties, field

I have this code:

```
foreach (FieldInfo mainField in typeof(MainWindow).GetFields())
            {
                FieldInfo field = mainField;
                foreach (PropertyInfo prop in field.FieldType.GetProperties())
                {                 
                        object propertyValue = null;
                        propertyValue = prop.GetValue(field.Name, null);
                        Console.WriteLine(propertyValue);             
                }
            }
```

My problem is with the

```
propertyValue = prop.GetValue(field.Name,null);
```

I get the error: Object does not match target type.
If i change it to

```
propertyValue = prop.GetValue(mgmtConfig,null);
```

it will work, but field.Name = mgmtConfig, so I dont understand what is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first parameter of the [GetValue method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.getvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is the object whose field value will be returned. So in your case it should be your `MainWindow` instance.

In the case of a static property the first parameter is ignored.